# What is the role of normalization function in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I learn machine learning and tried to build a simple tensorflow model. And when I tried to train the model my loss number was about 10.

`5s 83us/step - loss: 9.6847 - acc: 0.3971`

Code of the model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(),
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

But then I normalized the dataset using this code

`x_train = keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)`

And then loss fell to less than 1.

And the question is what does it do to make such a huge impact?

Comment: I believe this is due to the effect of feature scaling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"And the question is what does it do to make such a huge impact?"
It normalizes the training data to the l2 norm of the data [Implementation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/dd9109d152aea0e45d414edd3f4768b872807048/keras/utils/np_utils.py#L40). This is done so that no specific sample dominates how the updates are done to the weights. See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284427/why-should-we-normalize-data-for-deep-learning-in-keras) as well. In this answer, the reason for normalization is explained using a two feature logistic regression example.

Answer (score 1):

Normalizing means making changes to the features so they're all on a similar scale usually between 0 and 1. In your case, when you applied normalization using `keras.utils.normalize`, each feature was scaled individually to a normalized scale. This normalization procedure ensures that all features contribute equally to the learning process and prevents from domination by larger scales. It improves training efficiency and convergence which results in reduced loss in your model.